# include null values in date comparison mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

I have got 2 columns in my table with date ranges, one is start and the other is end. When I pass the value for searching from my Java program using hibernate, I want to get all those rows in which the value comes within the range.
For example:
If I pass '2008-08-29', It should bring all rows in the range 2008 - 2012 from columns 'start' and 'end'.
But there is another range 2012 to onwards for which start is '2012-07-01' but 'end' column has NULL values. What should I do in that case ?

Here is what I did. But it also brings some other rows which do not lie in this range.

```
SELECT * FROM `building_register_period` 
WHERE (@periodDate BETWEEN start_period_date AND end_period_date OR end_period_date IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
WHERE start_period_Date <= @periodDate 
AND (end_period_Date >= @periodDate OR end_period_Date IS NULL);
```

I would also always [advise against using `BETWEEN` with dates](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).

The problem with your query is that you are limiting to one of two conditions:

1. `@periodDate BETWEEN start_period_date AND end_period_date`
2. `end_period_date IS NULL`

Either one can be true to return a row, since your second predicate has no reference at all to `@periodDate` then you will end up with all rows where `end_period_date` is null, regardless of the `start_period_date`.